# Highcharts - Negative color with 'line' type polar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use a different color to represent negative values in a polar chart of type "line".

Is it wrong to say that this does not work?
It is definitely supported by the api. Very basic example [here](http://bit.ly/20boWmh).

Comment: negativeColor works best for individual data points. To color things the way you are trying to, look at the zones property: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones

Comment: The problem with negativeColor and line type series in polar chart looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts bug tracker - [#4936](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4936)

Comment: @jlbriggs Just tried using zones and doesn't appear to provide me with any joy. Just to be sure I've made sense of your suggestion, here's what I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/gcdt324y/1/

Comment: @dre you need to put the value and format together, like *{value:0,dashStyle: 'dot'}* however, it seems to have the same bug that Kacper noted above for the negativeColor - http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/gcdt324y/2/

Comment: Thanks @jlbriggs, will just have to keep an eye on the trackers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One idea you could try is overlaying an area series over the negative values, and then giving that area an opacity setting less than 100%.

So, for example, if your line is blue, overlay an area with a white background, set that area to, say, 20% opacity, and the result would be a lighter blue line in your negative values.

Here's how the values for that area series could be used:

```
color: '#FFFFFF', 
data: [ -1, -1, ... etc. for however many values you have in the chart ], 
fillOpacity: 0.2, /* 20% opacity */
lineWidth: 0, /* no borders for your area */
showInLegend: false, /* keeps the series from showing up in your legend */
type: 'area', 
zIndex: 1 /* set this higher than your lines so the area appears over them */
```

Just a thought, but I hope it helps!